# Does % block chance on a gear item other than shield work when you don't have a shield equpped?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are items in Diablo 3 other than a shield that give +% block chance such as [Helm of Command](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-helm-of-command). Does the bonus apply when you don't have a shield equipped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. I just tried it. With shield 28%, without shield and with Helm of Command 8%. Also tried to block without a shield but with Helm of Command. I blocked attacks.

EDIT: BUT you have no block amount, so if you block, you block nothing.

Comment: The result that I expected and you proved. Well done.

Comment: One reason something like this is interesting is you can block even without a shield equipped which effects certain skills... an example would be the heal from Renewal.